# How to save and display data in same view in functions in DJANGO

Tags: python, html, css, django, frameworks

I have two functions in my applications in which i am using one to save data in database and one to display data from database at the same time.

I don't know how this will work.

My Url is for the two functions

```
path('new_paper', views.newpaper_request, views.All_NewPaper),
```

Function to get data from database

In views

```
def All_NewPaper(request):
    newpapers = AnswerStudent.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'attempted.html', {'newpapers':newpapers})
```

In Template .html

```
{% for newpaper in newpaper %}
        {{ newpaper.Teacher_Name}}
      {% endfor %}
```

Function to Save data into database.

```
def newpaper_request(request):
    newpapers = NewPaper.objects.order_by('-id')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewPaperForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Saved")
            return redirect('/new_paper')
    else:
        form = NewPaperForm()
    return render(request, 'new_paper.html', {
        'form': form,
        'newpapers': newpapers,
    })
```

The code is correct for both functions if i pass only one of them.. But i want when someone open the page both of the functions should work..

Comment: Every view must have its separate url

Comment: Ok..But how i can pass these two functions in same view.

Comment: You can get away with using the same URL.  The difference is in the method, which you already have broken out with an IF statement.  Do one function in the POST, and the other function in GET.

Comment: Can you help me write a samll function for it on what do you mean...That would be realy helpful